# Wix Installation Directory Customization

Tags: wix

i have following condition for wix installer:
- Starting Installer directory for install should be RootDirectory\ApplicationName [C:\MYApplication]
- User should able to customize this path (using pathedit or any textbox )

I've done following code but problem is half of installation is done at specified path and half of folder is copied in the root directory.

```
<Fragment>
<Property Id="_BrowseProperty" Value="INSTALLDIR" Secure="yes"/>
<CustomAction Id="SetDataLocationDefault" Property="INSTALLDIR" Value="[WindowsVolume]$(var.Title)\" />
<InstallUISequence>
  <Custom Action="SetDataLocationDefault" After="CostFinalize" />
</InstallUISequence>
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="SetDataLocationDefault" After="CostFinalize" />
</InstallExecuteSequence>

<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="INSTALLDIR" Name="$(var.Title)">
    <Directory Id="ProgramMenuFolder">
      <Directory Id="ApplicationProgramsFolder" Name="$(var.Title)"/>
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
  <Directory Id="DesktopFolder"/>
</Directory>
```

Another file for the component includes

```
<Fragment>
<ComponentGroup Id="ProductInstallComponent">
  <ComponentRef Id="EXEPackage" />
  <ComponentRef Id="ProjectsOutput" />
  <ComponentRef Id="TempReports" />
  <ComponentRef Id="Help" />
  <ComponentRef Id="ApplicationShortcut" />
  <ComponentRef Id="ApplicationDeskShortcutComp" />
</ComponentGroup>
```

in the case Help Files and Report Files are created at the rootlocation. so how can i change that?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK such an action has to be set *before* the `CostFinalize`-action, as afterwards all the directories are set and unmutable. Also set it in both sequences, as you already did in the example above. I.e. it should be the following:

```
<InstallUISequence>
  <Custom Action="SetDataLocationDefault" Before="CostFinalize" />
</InstallUISequence>
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="SetDataLocationDefault" Before="CostFinalize" />
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Comment: Sorry...it didn't work out!! i also have pathedit used in this form and as mentioned above if i use Before="CostFinalize" than whole product installed in [WindowsVolume]\[ProductName] folder.